# Python map() dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I'm trying to use `map()` on the `dict_values` object returned by the `values()` function on a dictionary. However, I can't seem to be able to `map()` over a `dict_values`:

```
map(print, h.values())
Out[31]: <builtins.map at 0x1ce1290>
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this. What I'm actually trying to do is create a `set()` of all the `Counter` keys in a dictionary of `Counters`, doing something like this:

```
# counters is a dict with Counters as values
whole_set = set()
map(lambda x: whole_set.update(set(x)), counters.values())
```

Is there a better way to do this in Python?

Comment: Try to give example input/output - it makes it a lot easier to see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't know if you care about the first example, but this is equivalent: `print(*h.values(), sep='\n')` to a non-generator version of map.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Python 3, `map` returns an iterator, not a list. You still have to iterate over it, either by calling `list` on it explicitly, or by putting it in a `for` loop. But you shouldn't use `map` this way anyway. `map` is really for collecting return values into an iterable or sequence. Since neither `print` nor `set.update` returns a value, using `map` in this case isn't idiomatic.

Your goal is to put all the keys in all the counters in `counters` into a single set. One way to do that is to use a nested generator expression:

```
s = set(key for counter in counters.values() for key in counter)
```

There's also the lovely dict comprehension syntax, which is available in Python 2.7 and higher (thanks Lattyware!) and can generate sets as well as dictionaries:

```
s = {key for counter in counters.values() for key in counter}
```

These are both roughly equivalent to the following:

```
s = set()
for counter in counters.values():
    for key in counter:
        s.add(key)
```

Comment: Note that the slightly cleaner option here is to simply use a set comprehension, rather than a generator expression into the set constructor - `{key for counter in counters.values() for key in counter}`.

Answer (score 0):

You want the set-union of all the values of `counters`? I.e.,

```
counters[1].union(counters[2]).union(...).union(counters[n])
```

? That's just [functools.reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html):

```
import functools

s = functools.reduce(set.union, counters.values())
```

If `counters.values()` aren't already sets (e.g., if they're lists), then you should turn them into sets first. You can do it using a [dict comprehension](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) using `iteritems`, which is a little clunky:

```
>>> counters = {1:[1,2,3], 2:[4], 3:[5,6]}
>>> counters = {k:set(v) for (k,v) in counters.iteritems()}
>>> print counters
{1: set([1, 2, 3]), 2: set([4]), 3: set([5, 6])}
```

or of course you can do it inline, since you don't care about `counters.keys()`:

```
>>> counters = {1:[1,2,3], 2:[4], 3:[5,6]}
>>> functools.reduce(set.union, [set(v) for v in counters.values()])
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```